# How do you print two variables within brackets in Python 3?

Tags: python, variables, printing, var

I have this line of code:

```
print ("(x %s)(x %s)") % (var_p1, var_p2)
```

But it does not work, I am new to programming and I don't know what I have done wrong. Any experts out there with a simple answer?

I wanted it to randomly select an equation for a parabola. e.g. (x-3)(x+1) However, it comes up with the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
"File "E:/Python34/MyFiles/Math Study Buddy.py", line 26 in <module> 
print ("(x %s)(x %s)") % (var_p1, var_p2) 
TypeError: unsupported operand type (s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Use str.format `print ("(x {})(x {})".format(var_p1, var_p2))`

Comment: Thankyou @Padriac Cunningham, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
>>> var_p1 = 'test'
>>> var_p2 = 'test2'
>>> print(("(x {})(x {})".format(var_p1, var_p2))) 
(x test)(x test2)
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are in python 3 you need to put the variables inside the parenthesis  after your string:

```
>>> print ("(x %s)(x %s)"%(2, 3))
(x 2)(x 3)
```

*Note* that in python 3 `print` is a function and you need to pass the string as its argument.So you can not put your variables outside the function!

For more detail read [printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)

> **Note**
>
> The formatting operations described here exhibit a variety of quirks that lead to a number of common errors (such as failing to display tuples and dictionaries correctly). Using the newer [*str.format()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) interface helps avoid these errors, and also provides a generally more powerful, flexible and extensible approach to formatting text.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use 'x' to substitude variables here.
This will fix:

```
print ("(%s)(%s)") % (var_p1, var_p2)
```

also, .format is better than %

see:
[Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Comment: as mentioned, in python 3 you want aparenthesis around the whole thing you want to print. I'm using python2.7 here, so you may want to change a little bit.